# Rescheduling script in Netsuite

Tags: checkbox, netsuite

Having some issues in rescheduling a scheduled script for master item record here. I know that I need an exit criteria in the script otherwise the script will not know where to pick up from where it stopped, most likely a custom field in the form of checkbox. Everytime the script is ran, it checks the checkbox to true. During the next reschedule, records that are flagged will be ignored.

However, this script needs to be run daily. So that means the checkbox in all the records needs to be unchecked again, after the scheduler has completed the whole cycle for the day. This also means I'll require another scheduled script to reset all the flags in the item records at the end of the day. Could I be wrong or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try nlapiYieldScript.

nlapiYieldScript()

Creates a recovery point and then reschedules the script. The newly rescheduled script has its governance units reset, and is then placed at the back of the scheduled script queue. To summarize, nlapiYieldScript works as follows:

Creates a new recovery point.
Creates a new scheduled script with a governance reset.
Associates the recovery point to the scheduled script.
Puts the script at the back of the scheduled script queue.

Comment: This is something new. Do you have any examples on how to use this API? What are the parameters parsed?

Comment: Use it just how it looks. While at the bottom of a loop, check for remaining governance usage. If below a certain level (500 is an arbitrary amount), call the function.

Answer (score 0):

A little more detail about exactly what this script accomplishes might help, but here is how we normally handle rescheduling our scripts.

Typically, the scheduled script is performing a search to locate all of the records it will need to operate on. We sort this search by `internalid` and update the "last ID processed" as the script runs. Once we are ready to reschedule, we store the last ID processed in a script parameter and pass that in to the reschedule function. The search has a filter of "internalid greater than lastIDParameter". All the previous values are then filtered out of the search because it has been sorted by internalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can have datestamp as the custom field instead of a checkbox and search for datestamp field with yesterday's records.